# Angular providedIn 'root' not working for global error handler but using NgModule providers works

Tags: angular

I am creating a global error handling service in Angular and I am reading about the `@Injectable` annotation.

My `GlobalErrorHandlerService` looks like

```
Injectable() // <- using this and adding it in @NgModule providers WORKS!
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(...) { }

  handleError(error: any): any{
    console.log(error);
  }
```

And in my **app.module.ts**, I added it to the `providers` array

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
.   ...
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: GlobalErrorHandlerService //<- if added here, it works
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, in my `@Component`, if an error (client or server) occurs, I simply rethrow it like below and my `GlobalErrorHandlerService` `handleError()` method is called as expected:

```
  private getCar(String carId) {
    this.searchService.retrieveCar(carId).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        ...
      },
      error: (error) => {
        throw error;  // -> rethrow error to be handled  by global error handler
      },
      complete: () => {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
```

All good so far.

However, from my reading, the recommendation is that instead of using `@NgModule` `providers` array, we should now use `providedIn root` like below:

```
Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root', // <- using this without adding it in @NgModule providers DOES NOT WORK!
}) 
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private errorMessageService: ErrorMessageService, private injector: Injector, private zone: NgZone) { }

  handleError(error: any): any{

    console.log(error);
  }
```

Using `providedIn: 'root'` should not require adding this service to `@NgModule providers` array in **app.module.ts**.  But it does not work and my `GlobalErrorHandlerService` `handleError()` method is never called if I use `providedIn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` only works when requesting directly the instance

For example :

```
Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService {}

/////////

public class MyClass {
   constructor(handler: GlobalErrorHandlerService) {
      // OK
   }
}
```

But since the error handler is looking for the `ErrorHandler` class you need to explicitly do the binding between `ErrorHandler` <=> `GlobalErrorHandlerService`.

That's what the explicit provider declarations are for !

You can do this in an `NgModule` or in the options of `bootstrapApplication`, like you already did !

Comment: Thnak you.  What do you mean by "binding between ErrorHandler <=> GlobalErrorHandlerService"?  Mind explaining how can I do that other than using @NgModule?  Thanks again

Comment: There is only one other way, the providers of `bootstrapApplication()` if you use standalone components !

Comment: I find that your suggested solution only works if in addition to using ```providedIn``, I also use ```@NgModule providers``` array in app.module.ts which is confusing as based on my reading, using ```providedIn``` means you dont have to use ```@NgModule```.  I am not really looking for "other way", I am just looking for solution on how to use ```providedIn``` for global error handling as I dont see it working

Comment: providedIn:'root' can't work globally for classes that are not directly injected. The framework is asking for `ErrorHandler`, so you have to give it the mapping !

Comment: And by "mapping" you mean @NgModule providers or you mean injecting global handler into the c-tor?  Thamks

Comment: yes, the providers array in an NgModule or a Component.